# Extract widgets from android source code

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have downloaded android 5.0 source with the android manager. I am wondering if it contains the whole source code or only some parts. I'd like to extract the android easter egg you enable by tapping the about button. But I don't know how to find it inside the source. Where should I look at?